# iCloud, Core Data, and data from web services in iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, icloud, core-data-migration

I'm writing a pretty simple application for tracking, storing, and organizing movies that are fed from iTunes and RottenTomatoes. I pull the movies down in a large back, usually ~150 movies at a time. The user can then view the feed and add movies to custom made lists.

The problem I'm running into is pulling data from the web and syncing with iCloud producing duplicates of the movies.

I've been considering breaking the movie feed into a local store (remove from iCloud) and then create the lists and other user values in either a separate iCloud Core Data store or even use iCloud key value storage (though saving movie lists will probably be rough).

This is my first app with iCloud, so I'm using some boilerplate from [this objc.io article](http://www.objc.io/issue-10/icloud-core-data.html). I've done some modifications because my web syncing uses a background NSManagedObjectContext to do the work. The background MOC saves and then my main MOC merges changes in. The UI is primarily NSFetchedResultsControllers, so this entire system works really seamlessly.

Here is some code for handling iCloud NSNotifications

```
// happens when the main MOC saves
- (void)managedObjectContextDidSaveNotification:(NSNotification *)notification {
    @synchronized(self) {
        NSManagedObjectContext *moc = self.backgroundManagedObjectContext;

        [moc performBlock:^{
            [moc mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:notification];
        }];
    }
}

// happens when the bg MOC saves
- (void)backgroundManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification:(NSNotification *)notification {
    @synchronized(self) {
        NSManagedObjectContext *moc = self.managedObjectContext;

        [moc performBlock:^{
            [moc mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:notification];
        }];
    }
}

- (void)persistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChanges:(NSNotification *)notification {
    @synchronized(self) {
        NSManagedObjectContext *moc = self.managedObjectContext;

        [moc performBlock:^{
            [moc mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:notification];
        }];
    }
}

- (void)storesWillChange:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSManagedObjectContext *moc = self.managedObjectContext;

    [moc performBlockAndWait:^{            
        NSError *error = nil;
        if ([moc hasChanges] && [moc save:&error]) {
            DDLogInfo(@"MOC saved succesfully");
        }
        else {
            DDLogError(@"Error saving MOC: %@",error);
        }
    }];
}

- (void)storesDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification {}
```

I originally thought I could add some logic in once iCloud finished merging changes, but that doesn't look very reliable as I could end up in a loop of changes between devices.

Any thoughts on how this could be made possible? I'm sure people have done this before, I just can't find any helpful resources on it.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your situation properly, it is possible that the user downloads the same movie on two different devices at about the same time, and after syncing up, you have a duplicate of the movie.

Apple's advice for this situation is simply to de-dupe after any iCloud merge. You do a fetch looking for objects with the same movie id, and you sort the duplicates in a deterministic way, and delete one. If you don't sort them, you might delete one object on one device, and a different object on the other device, and end up with no objects.

This article has efficient code for seeking duplicates: http://www.atomicbird.com/blog/icloud-complications-part-2

If you don't like this whole post-merge de-duplication, frameworks like [TICDS](https://github.com/nothirst/TICoreDataSync) and [Ensembles](http://ensembles.io) allow you to provide global ids, which remove the necessity to de-dupe. (Disclosure: I develop Ensembles)

Comment: So with sorting, will that avoid any kind of "delete cycle" where one device deletes dup a, other device deletes dup b, they sync a & b, then repeat? In theory, both devices would delete dup a?

Comment: Yes. The idea is that they both should delete the same thing. If that happens, there should not be any ping-pong, or data loss.